# disable/overwrite flexslider with media queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, media-queries, flexslider

On a landing page I'm building I have 3 testimonials displayed in 3 columns on the desktop version of the site. On mobile/smaller screen devices the 3 testimonials need to be displayed in a slideshow (one at a time).

I thought a good solution for this would be to use the [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) jQuery plugin, which I've used for years and love.

I dropped the testimonials into the list-items of the Flexslider and it all worked great as a slideshow. Now, at a resolution of 768px and above I need the 3 columned layout to display which would mean overwriting Flexsliders styles. I thought I could do this with just CSS and maybe a checky `!important` here or there to overwrite the layout but unfortunately this doesn't work. As Flexslider puts the widths inline with javascript I seemingly can't overwrite them so can't get the layout I'm after.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? Ideally the layout would change on browser resize too which is why I wanted to use CSS if I could.

For reference here is my HTML:

```
<div class="flexslider" id="testimonials">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <blockquote>
                    <p>I'm losing over a pound a week. I don’t think about food, especially at snack time.</p>
                    <footer>
                        <p>Lorna, 41 <span>Lost 8lb, dropped 1 dress size</span></p>
                    </footer>
                </blockquote>
            </li>
            <li>
                <blockquote>
                    <p>I lost half a stone without dieting.</p>
                    <footer>
                        <p>Tina, 42 <span>Lost 6lb</span></p>
                    </footer>
                </blockquote>
            </li>
            <li>
                <blockquote>
                    <p>This really helps, because it means I get to eat what I want but just not as much of it!</p>
                    <footer>
                        <p>Imogen Thomas <span>Glamour model</span></p>
                    </footer>
                </blockquote>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And my Flexslider code:

```
$(function(){
if($(".flexslider").length > 0) {
    $(".flexslider").addClass("loading");
    // Can also be used with $(document).ready()
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            slideshowSpeed: 10000,
            animationSpeed: 400,
            easing: "easeInQuad",
            controlNav: true,
            directionNav: false,
            useCSS: false,
            start: function(slider){
                $('.flexslider').removeClass('loading');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

});

Thanks, hope someone can help! :)
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the solution I went for was to check the width of the container and if it's below a resolution of 768 pixels add the class of `flexslider` to the div. If it's above the class will not be added allowing CSS styling without all the generated flexslider inline styles!

The code I used below, I have very little javascript knowledge so I'm sure there'll be a better way of doing this - but hopefully someone finds it useful :)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $('#testimonials').addClass('flexslider');
}
});

$(function(){
if($(".flexslider").length > 0) {
    $(".flexslider").addClass("loading");
    // Can also be used with $(document).ready()
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            slideshowSpeed: 10000,
            animationSpeed: 400,
            easing: "easeInQuad",
            controlNav: true,
            directionNav: false,
            useCSS: false,
            start: function(slider){
                $('.flexslider').removeClass('loading');
            }
        });
    });
}
});
```